# what is difference that make assignment and direct assignment of slice,channel and map in GO language

Tags: go

I'm new to go language, look this code section

```
a := make(map[string]string, 10)
a["name"] = "Blob"
// or
b := map[string]string{}
b["name"] = "Blob"
```

> Questions:
>
> > Does "make" allocate memory on heap?
> >
> > Does the "make" function only add one step to the initialization operation? like combination of malloc and memset in C language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `make(map[string]string, 10)` provides a capacity hint for the map and the composite literal `map[string]string{}` does not.

The maps are allocated on the heap in both cases.

The `make` function allocates and initializes an object as does the composite literal.